# Separar palabras de una cadena y contar las ocurrencias

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta de mysql

```
SELECT comorbilidades, COUNT( comorbilidades ) AS total
FROM  covid_19_paciente
GROUP BY comorbilidades
ORDER BY comorbilidades DESC
```

que me da los resultados de la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito separar las palabras de los campos mediante el carácter ',' coma y después contarlas. Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTA: los nombres de as comorbilidades y el total de esta ultima imagen es un ejemplo.

Como son muchas comorbilidades no puedo poner una condición, intente con la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT DISTINCT comorbilidades,
(SELECT COUNT(comorbilidades) FROM covid_19_paciente WHERE comorbilidades LIKE '%hta%' || comorbilidades LIKE '%HIPERTENSION%' )  AS HTA, 
(SELECT COUNT(comorbilidades) FROM covid_19_paciente WHERE comorbilidades LIKE '%dm%' || comorbilidades LIKE '%DIABETES%')  AS DM, 
(SELECT COUNT(comorbilidades) FROM covid_19_paciente WHERE comorbilidades LIKE '%VIH%')  AS VIH, 
(SELECT COUNT(comorbilidades) FROM covid_19_paciente WHERE comorbilidades LIKE '%OBSESIDAD%')  AS OBSESIDAD, 
(SELECT COUNT(comorbilidades) FROM covid_19_paciente WHERE comorbilidades LIKE '%asma%')  AS ASMA, 
(SELECT COUNT(comorbilidades) FROM covid_19_paciente WHERE comorbilidades LIKE '%Tabaquismo, %')  AS Tabaquismo, 
(SELECT COUNT(comorbilidades) FROM covid_19_paciente WHERE comorbilidades LIKE '%IRC%')  AS IRC
FROM covid_19_paciente
```

y me da el siguiente resultado pero no es lo que nesesito.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano Gracias!!!

metodo PDO

```
ARCHIVO conexion.php

class Conexion
{
    private static $instancia;
    private $dbh;
    private function __construct()
    {
        try
        {/*
            #$this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx','root', '');

            $this->dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
            $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }

    public static function singleton()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$instancia))
        {
            $miclase = __CLASS__;
            self::$instancia = new $miclase;
        }
        return self::$instancia;
    }

    public function prepare($sql)
    {
        return $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    }

    public function lastInsertId()
    {
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function __clone()
    {
        trigger_error("La clonación del objeto no está permitida");
    }

}
```

Esta es la clase crud.

```
require_once('conexion.php');

    class Crud
    {

        public $insertInto;
        public $insertColumns;
        public $insertValues;
        public $mensaje;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->dbh = Conexion::singleton();
        }
        public function crear()
        {
            try
            {
                $insertInto = $this->insertInto;
                $insertColumns = $this->insertColumns;
                $insertValues = $this->insertValues;

                $sql = "INSERT INTO $insertInto($insertColumns)VALUES($insertValues)";
                $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
                if(!$query)
                {
                    $this->mensaje = '<script type="text/javascript">
                                        alert("Error no se pudo crear el Registro");
                                    </script>';
                    $this->dbh = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    $query->execute();
                    $this->mensaje = '<script>
                                        alert("Registro Creado Correctamente");
                                    </script>';
                    $this->dbh = null;

                }

            }catch(PDOException $ex)
            {
                $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
}

$atn = new Crud();
$atn->insertInto = "tabla";
$atn->insertColumns = 'id, nombre, comorbilidades';
$atn->insertValues = "'$id','$nombre','$comorbilidades'";
$atn->crear();
```

Comment: y cual es el resultado que esperas puedes danos un ejemplo con un par de `comorbilidades`

Comment: el ejemplo que espero es el de la segunda imagen.

Comment: usas php o quieres que el mysql haga el análisis que en realidad debería hacer php? con el resultado del primer query php haria mas rapido lo que esperas en la segunda imagen.

Comment: En cualquier de las dos opciones me es de utilidad, puse mysql por que es el que mas utilizo para hacer consultas. Pero si me puedes ayudar en php seria genial.

Comment: ok entonces muéstrame como haces en el PHP para capturar el resultado... usas mysqli o PDO???

Comment: agregalo a tu post no uses comentarios para compartir código. otra cosa el código que colocaste inserta; no es de consulta; por eso tee pregunt como haces consultas?

Comment: Me parece que el problema de fondo es de diseño. ¿Por qué esos datos están tan mal representados (separados por comas)? ¿Por qué no hacer uso de uno de los pilares de las bases de datos que es el modelo relacional? Imagina que `diabetes, asma, hta` etc tienen cada uno un ID en una tabla llamada `enfermedad` por ejemplo y usas ese ID en otra tabla asociativa para gestionar la enfermedad que tiene cada paciente. Haciendo eso la obtención de datos estadísticos sería mucho más simple y la base de datos estaría menos cargada de datos redundantes como todos esos separados por coma.

Comment: el no quiere re-hacer toda la aplicación basada en la **opinión** de otro programador, que sugiere cambiar el diseño de su base de datos, sin tomar en cuenta el impacto que tendría; el ha planteado un problema en la manipulación de los datos en mysql el cual quiere resolver en el query MySql o mediante PHP.

Comment: Estas en lo correcto en un inicio esa era mi idea pero me pidieron que deje el campo abierto,para que escriban el nombre de la comorbilidad lo que estoy intentando hacer es conocer las diferentes comorbilidades para hacer una lista de las mas comunes y dejar un campo para otras.

Answer (score 0):

si la respuesta de la base de datos de cada registro es como la imagen #1;
entonces te recomiendo usar PHP una vez tengas ese resultado;

### Query BD:

```
SELECT comorbilidades,
FROM  covid_19_paciente
GROUP BY comorbilidades
ORDER BY comorbilidades DESC
```

### Generamos una array con los datos Crudos (Big Data):

Luego en algún lugar me imagino en php recibes esos dato de alguna variable como `$resultPDO` de la consulta, entonces guardarias todas las posibles respuestas:

```php
$comorbilidadesBIGDATA = [];
while ($row = $resultPDO->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $comorbilidadesBIGDATA = array_fill(explode(',',$row['comorbilidades']);
}
```

### Analizamos los datos extraídos:

una ves que tenga esto hacemos un mapeo de la variable `$comorbilidadesBIGDATA` y analizamos las ocurrencias:

#### Opción #1

```php
function unserialize_unique_count($input, $k = 'count') {
    $a = [];
    foreach ($input as $d) {
        $s = serialize($d);
        $a[$s] = (isset($a[$s]) ? ($a[$s] + 1) : 1);
    }
    foreach ($a as $s => $c) {
        $a[$s] = unserialize($s) + [ $k => $c ];
    }
    return array_values($a);
}
$grouped_with_count = unserialize_unique_count($comorbilidadesBIGDATA);
```

#### Opción #2

Tambien se pude de esta otra forma:

```php
$vals = array_count_values($comorbilidadesBIGDATA);
arsort($vals);
foreach($vals as $key => $value){
    // esto esta separado para mejor comprensión:
    echo $key; //Enfermedad
    echo '=>'; 
    echo $value; //veces encontrada
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Este código no lo he probado ya que no cuento con los datos suficientes de parte de [isela rojo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/70132/isela-rojo)

PD no es exacto por que depende de lo que escriban, y que cosas escriban.